# Validation rule to restrict up to 3 repetitive characters

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

Can anyone please give me a Validation Rule syntax may be using REGEX to stop the duplicate 4 characters in a standard field.?
Basically the field can accept aa, aaa but not aaaa. I want to restrict the field with max. 3 repetitive characters and more than 3 will give an error.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that attempt. Using regex in a validation rule isn't really that different from using regex anywhere else (on the Salesforce platform, or otherwise). I'd think that using `{4,}` to check for 4 or more of something would be the simplest. That, of course, isn't the _entire_ regex. If you don't understand how that'd fit in, then it'd be worth your time to go through some regex tutorials first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use backreferences:

```
REGEX(Name,'.*(.)\\1{3}.*')
```

Which reads as follows:

```
 .* Any number of preceding characters
  ( Start numbered capture group
  . Any one specific character
  ) End numbered capture group
\\1 Backreference to capture group 1
{3} Repeated 3 times (four total instances of the same character
 .* Any number of subsequent characters
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you..!! :)